# Where to put autostart scrips to run after x display server has been started?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager, manjaro, x-server

I'm using manjaro linux with dwm (dynamic window manager) and I need to run some some commands that will only work after the x display server has been started. Lightdm is being used to login.

example commands:

```
/usr/bin/xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --right-of HDMI1
/usr/bin/xset r rate 280 40
/usr/bin/copyq
```

I've tried adding these to `~/.xinitrc`, `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, `crontab` with a delay and `~/.xsession`

Placing them in `~/.xession` did run them but then only the wallpaper loads and the window manager is never started.

Putting them in the user's `crontab` gave output such as this:
`Can't open display`

`xset:  unable to open display ""`

`ERROR: QtFatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.`

Where is the appropriate place to put commands such as these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightDM is the program which starts your X display server (hence "display manager"), so the commands should be in a place that LightDM looks in. (The other good alternative is using your window manager "autostart" script if it has one – but unfortunately dwm doesn't.)

For LightDM, `~/.xsession` is a good place, but note that it is run synchronously – that is, your session only gets started after the xsession script *ends*. So if you want to start any long-running commands, you must run them "in background" with the `&` operator:

```
/usr/bin/copyq &
```

GDM instead uses `~/.xprofile` in the same way.

Scripts can also be placed in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*` with the same requirements.

---

`~/.xinitrc` is similar, but it is typically *not used* by display managers; only startx and SDDM read it, while other DMs find the session configuration in /usr/share/xsessions instead. Additionally, xinitrc also has the job of starting the actual session – i.e. it needs to invoke `dwm` at the very end.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting really frustrated. I should have thought of putting them in the background.